# Verificar se valor já está salvo no sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html

É a primeira dúvida que posto e vou tentar passar a informação mais clara possível. Tenho o código abaixo ao qual eu salvo no `sessionStorage` o valor do elemento clicado, o problema é que se clicar várias vezes, o valor irá se repetir várias vezes também. Como pretendo enviar esse valor posteriormente para o bd, qual a melhor forma de eu limitar que esse valor se repita ao clicar no objeto?

```
<script>
    var numeros = document.querySelectorAll("#teste div p");
    for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        numeros[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            const num = e.target || e.srcElement;
            const name = num.innerHTML;
            const dataObj = { name };
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('items') === null) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify([dataObj]));
            } else {
                sessionStorage.setItem(
                    'items',
                    JSON.stringify([
                        ...JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('items')),
                        dataObj
                    ])
                );
            }
            renderItem(dataObj);
        })
    }
</script>
<script>
    function renderItem(item) {
        $('.items').append(`
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <strong>${item.name}</strong>
            </div>`);
    }
    function getItems() {
        const items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('items'));

        items.forEach(item => renderItem(item));
    }
    getItems();
</scr
```

ipt>

Comment: Pergunta ficou vaga!

Comment: Só por curiosidade, não sei se você sabe mas os dados no [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) tem os seus dados apagados ao expirar a sessão da página.

Answer (score 1):

O valor se repete pq sua condição diz q se for `null` salva no `sessionStorage`, caso não seja `null` (caindo no else), salva também, a diferença é que você está puxando tudo que já existe no sessionStorage e concatena com o dataObj.

Ao invés de usar o else, você pode trabalhar melhor em uma condição pensando em um **ÚNICO** cenário que deve ser salvo no sessionStorage

Agora se você quiser manter itens únicos, você consegue usar o Set:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3];
console.log([...new Set(arr)]); // [1, 2, 3]
```